# First Gear requires stepping on gas pedal before engaging (sometimes)

Tags: honda, manual-transmission, gears, fit

I have a [2008 Honda Fit 1st gen](http://www.automobile-catalog.com/car/2007/1137170/honda_fit_1_3a.html)

[image]

I pull the lever to the 1st gear slot and i feel it doesn't engange, but if i maintain that little pressure and i blip the throttle the lever goes into first (i dont feel any grinding or strange noise).

Car has 74k miles and new MT fluid and otherwise it runs perfectly.

Is this a common feature of this car? Other cars in general? Synchros wearing?

This is my first car, so I don't have much experience to know the difference.

Comment: Have you tried pumping the clutch pedal a couple of times before trying to move it into first gear? Are you sure you're pushing down on the clutch all the way? Have you checked the clutch fluid reservoir (I don't know if it uses the brake reservoir for fluid or not)?

Comment: De-clutching and clutching again works. Engaging 2nd first and then 1st works too. All fluids are somewhat new (changed a year ago) and everything is in check. The clutch is pushed properly. Only 1st does that.

Comment: If you give it a period of time after pushing the clutch pedal in (releasing the clutch and waiting, say, 5-10 seconds), can you then put it in 1st without doing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes different gear oils help. In my 2007 Honda Accord, 3rd gear engagement was very similar to your 1st gear. Either it wouldn't go into gear all the time without excessive force, or would require letting the clutch out a little bit while pushing on the gear lever to engage the dogs. Once I changed the gear oil from the factory 40w oil to Pennzoil Synchromesh (though other "synchromesh" fluids would likely also work fine), shifting has been seamless ever since.

In general, some gearboxes are known for having issues like this. I'm not if it is a common issue for your car in particular, though.